# Powershell Azure Pester Test

Tags: unit-testing, powershell, pester

Below is a simple function that just creates a resource group and exports the data. I am trying to learn unit test but I cant seem to figure it out.

Is it possible to give the test mock data? and can I test if the output file would work?

```
function New-AzureRG{

    param([string]$rgName,
     [string]$location

    )

$getData =  New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $rgName -location 'WestEurope'

$getData | Export-Csv $location

}


Describe "New-AzureRG" {
    Context "Function Exists" {
        It "Should return a message" {
        $sum = New-AzureRG -rgName testRG -location C:\tst\testsc.csv
        ($um).Name | Should Be "testRG"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my terrible attempt to make a test using pester. For some reason the test is actually doing it, instead of making it as a test. Im just confused :(.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think your test is actually working. For example in the test $um is not assigned... If you mock the New-AzureRG function in your current test you are testing nothing. I guess you want something like:

Make a function c

Call the function from an other function

Mock the New-AzureRG function in your test

You mock can look something like:

```
Mock New-AzureRG { return @{Name = "NameRG"} } -ParameterFilter { $Name -eq "NameRG" }
```